# When clicking submit the form redirects to the registration manager

Tags: php, html, forms

I am attemping to create a PHP login system using MySQLi.
However I have created an HTML Form:

```
<form action="register_manager.php" method="post">
    <p>Please fill all fields!</p>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="<?PHP print $getuser; ?>" maxlength="15" /><br />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" maxlength="15" />
    <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" />
    <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        (Use a vaid a valid E-Mail Address for activation!)
    </p>
    <p>
        <a href="#">Already got an account?</a>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="regsubmit" value="Register"/><br />
    <?PHP echo '<p>'.$errormsg.'</p>'; ?>
</form>
```

Once I click submit, it redirects me to the registration_manager.php page, which is not what I want it to do. I am new to PHP so I am not aware on why it is doing this, instead of registering the user.

This is the register_manager.php file:
http://pastebin.com/cvbA6L6P

Comment: Submit button usually submits all  the form data to the action specified in the form: <form action="register_manager.php

Comment: Where do you want the form to submit?

Answer (score 0):

The action specified in your form is `register_manager.php` so whenever you hit the submit button you will get redirected there. Also, in the link you provided of the source code of `register_manager.php`, you're generating error messages, depending on the case, but never printing them on the page so the user can see what is wrong, unless of course the html form you provided is included in the `register_manager.php`. Finally, when testing make sure you fill all the requirements set by the if statements in you `register_manager.php` file, i.e. pass all wanted fields (username, email (which must be longer than 7 chars, containing the '@' and '.' characters), password, password confirmation). Hope this solves your question!

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is normal. The browser will send a POST request to the URL defined as action. So you need to render the form there as well. You can either abstract the form out and reuse it in both files or do the initial form rendering and the processing in one file by checking if `$_POST['regsubmit']` is set (if it is not set you are rendering the form initially).

Answer (score 0):

Submit button will activate the request of the webpage specified in the attribute `action`, passing the information inside the form by the method selected. In your example, the information is passed to `register_manager.php` using `POST` method.

To retrieve the information passed, you could use the arrays `$_POST` and `$_GET` depending the method used. In your example:

```
<?php
print $_POST['password'];
print $_POST['confirmpassword'];
print $_POST['email'];
?>
```